# Web.xml Override Descriptors for tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, jetty, web.xml

I am deploying a war file to tomcat, however I am wanting to override my deployment descriptor web.xml, the purpose is to have a web app customized for different environments.

I use a jetty demo launcher rather than deploying to tomcat each time, I found out that jetty can do this which works:

```
Server server = new Server(9090);
WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext("src/main/webapp", "/");
List<String> overrideDescriptors = new ArrayList<String>();
overrideDescriptors.add("src/main/resources/jetty-override-web.xml");
context.setOverrideDescriptors(overrideDescriptors);

context.setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
server.setHandler(context);
server.start();
server.join();
```

I'm no tomcat warrior or anything so please bear with me. My question is is there any config in tomcat I can use to achieve the same thing for when I deploy my war file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set default deploiment properties in `conf/web.xml` in your Tomcat.
You can follow these informations for more details: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/config/context.html (chapter Automatic Context Configuration).

Comment: Sorry about the delay, answer accepted! That will allow me to customize for different environments thanks!